# CSS dont print unchecked/selected radio buttons or checkboxes

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button, checkbox

I have a form that I want a separate CSS file for printing. On the screen there are other radio buttons and checkboxes. But I want those unchecked radio buttons and checkboxes to hide when I print them.

Is there a way to use jQuery to set classes on those labels and corresponding checkboxes so the @media print hides them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within an `@media print { ... }` block you can hide *all* the checkboxes and then display *only the checked* checkboxes.

To target these checked checkboxes use the `checked` attribute of the input.

```
@media print {
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"][checked="checked"] {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XfpM6/ it shows only the two selected checkboxes.

**EDIT:**

To hide the label you could use the `+` selector, which targets the direct sibling.
It would be:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"][checked="checked"] + label {
    display: inline;
}
```

(Supposing you have the HTML in this way `<input type="checkbox" .. /> <label for="..">Label</label>`, otherwise you have to add a class to each `label` to hide).

Regarding the `media print`, did you add that css *after* the `screen` css?

Another solutions could be to get rid of the `@media print` block, and include the css with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="print" />
```

at the end of your css links (so it overrides the other rules).

This would be the same, the key thing is that you include this css **after the `screen` css**.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that IE6 doesn't support this.

Comment: I have a lot of my code that wont work with IE6 so i have an alert box that comes up if they user has an older browser.

Comment: doesnt work. Plus i want to hide the corresponding labels too. Here's the page. [link](http://agent.thepiagency.com/agents/intake.php?id=2)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using CSS, just check for the presence of the `checked` attribute

```
@media print{
  input[type="checkbox"]
  {
    visibility: hidden;
  }


  input[type="checkbox"][checked]
  {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L3Bwp/1/

Comment: Both answers show this working in normal CSS but doesnt prove it works in @media print. See my reply above for the link to a sample page.

Comment: The only way you can prove it works is to do a print preview in the browser.

Comment: I did and they ALL disappear. The checked ones dont come back. I'm testing in Firefox 4